# PHP Can't perform echo or other syntax while do boostrapping

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

So recently I try to make php MVC, and then I do boostrapping method for load classes to `/public/index.php` , when i was done with the boostrapping,I do simple testing which I try to perform the `__construct()` method inside the App class in `/app/core/App.php`, but when I open `/public/index.php` in browser,nothing happend, and I try to echo something inside `/public/index.php` just same, nothing happend

But when i remove the `require_once "../app/init.php";`, the echo just work perfectly, i have no idea what happend :(, please show me what's wrong with my code and why it can happend

---

### **My goal :**

1. make sure that my boostrapping correct
2. to perform echo in browser for checking that the boostrapping success

### Expected result :

1. echo a string from App's `__construct()` to browser

### My code :

[project's directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJikv.png)

1. Inside `/app/core/App.php`

```
<?php

class App{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "ok!";
    }
}
```

2. Inside `/app/init.php`

```
<?php

require_once 'core/App.php';
require_once 'core/Controllers.php';
```

3. Inside `/public/index.php`

```
<?php

require_once '../app/init.php';

$app = new App;
echo "test";
```

### Edit : Errors message

```php
 Warning: require_once(./core/App.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpmvc/app/init.php on line 3

 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required './core/App.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpmvc/app/init.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpmvc/public/index.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpmvc/app/init.php on line 3
```

Comment: Probably some `require_once` call fails, but you have error display turned off…? Consult your server logs…

Comment: While developing, you should enable and display error messages.

Comment: @deceze  thanks for the information, right know i have error message, but unfortunately I still confused with these errors,

Comment: Note that relative imports are relative to the current *working directory*, not the file they're in (more specifically to the `include_path` mentioned in the error, which includes `.`, the current working directory). You usually want to use absolute paths explicitly to avoid that: `require_once __DIR__ . '/../...'`.